# Two's complement- Calculate minmal number of bits needed for result

Tags: math, binary, addition, twos-complement

let's say we have two decimal numbers:

- -15 = `10001` in two's complement, **5 bits**
- -9 = `10111` in two's complement, **5 bits**

Now, result of addition of those two numbers is -24 = `101000` in two's complement, **6 bits**

My question is: Is it possible to get minimal number of bits needed to store the result before even calculating it?

Sorry for bad grammar/expressing things

Comment: The result of adding two numbers will always take at most one bit more than the longest of those two numbers (even if they have a different sign). But it should be noted that "two's complement" doesn't make a lot of sense if the number of bits is not fixed. For instance, with your variable-size notation, `10001` is -15, but `010001` is +17 ?!

Comment: @Stef Thanks for responding. Yes, `010001` would be 17, that's how I was taught at least. I got an assignment where I have to adjust number of bits in -15 and -9 to get -24 correctly, previously I have to give minimal number of bits needed for the result. I think your answer narrows it down

Comment: Perhaps you're supposed to convert -15 and -9 to the new number of bits first? -15 becomes 110001 and -9 becomes 110111, then you can add them together. Still, I find it extremely odd and error-prone to allow for a variable number of bits with two's complement. The fact that 10001 and 010001 are not the same number, but 110001 and 10001 are the same number, defies all intuition.

Comment: 'Perhaps you're supposed to convert -15 and -9 to the new number of bits first?'
that's it. Thank you once more